# No response back from ajax .post to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a username availability check. I don't seem to be getting a response back though. I don't get any errors in the console, just the 200 OK but with no response, which should be the $result?

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['signusername']) && !empty($_POST['signusername'])){
    $signusername= $_POST['signusername'];
    $result='';
    if(checkUsername($signusername, $conn) == TRUE){
    $result='user found';  
    }else{
    $result='user not found';
    }
    echo $result;
}
```

jquery:

```
$.post('username_check.php', { signusername: username }, function (result)//not getting this back
                {
                    if (result == 'user not found')
                    {
                        $('.error').text('Avaliable');
                    } else if (result == 'user found')
                    {
                        $('.error').text('Taken');
                    }
                });
```

If I change the 'else if' to an 'else' it will work and display 'taken', if i change result='' it still doesn't work.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

edit-

```
function checkUsername($signusername, $conn) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info where username= '".$signusername."'");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $signusername);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
               return TRUE;
            }
            };
```

This is the function for checking the username, I also use it for checking if the username is taken after the form has been submitted, it works fine. Maybe the problem lies with this function?

Comment: `function ($result)` - `if ($result == 'user not found')` - `else if ($result == 'user found')`

Comment: That part is jquery though? Would it still work?

Comment: Probably, give it a try. What you're telling it to do is `if the (result) function` when using `if (result` - Usual syntax is a variable `if ($result`. However, have a look at the answer below. It looks like it makes sense. Try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['signusername']) && !empty($_POST['signusername'])){
    $signusername= $_POST['signusername'];
    $result='';

    if(checkUsername($signusername, $conn) == TRUE){
        $found = true;  
    } else {
        $found = false;
    }

    echo json_encode(array('userFound' => $found));
}
```

JS:

```
$.post('username_check.php', { signusername: username }, function (data) {
    if (data.userFound == false) {
        $('.error').text('Avaliable');
    } else if (data.userFound == true) {
        $('.error').text('Taken');
    } else {
        $('.error').text('Error checking for username avaliablility');
    }
}, 'json')
.error(function(e){
    console.log(e); // Look at your JS console for more info
    $('.error').text('Error checking for username avaliablility');
});
```

Comment: It also maybe best to change `echo` to `die(json_encode...)` to make sure nothing else gets returned that may confuse jQuery.

Comment: I changed it. Tested it by typing in 'a', I get an error, console says:  Object { readyState=4, responseText="\n\n".   I don't understand at all -_-

Comment: I dont think that the issue is within the code posted then. try doing something like `die("testing123");` after the if() in the PHP and see if you get the testing123 returned?

Comment: Is it possible it is the checkusername function? I use the same code to check if the username is taken when form is submitted. Maybe it doesn't work the same way? I edited the question with the code. I hope you can help, I've been trying to figure it out on my own but I've obviously gotten too ahead of myself with all this.

Comment: If it works when the formed submitted then I doubt it. Try my suggestion by using `die` to debug.

Comment: Nothing comes up. If I place it after the if(isset) or the if(checkusername).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58621/discussion-between-jono20201-and-user1375823).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when trying to compare AJAX responses directly, there is almost always hidden or special characters making a direct comparison difficult at best. Instead wrap your response in XML or JSON, not only will it look cleaner it will be easier to manage.

Comment: So I put the data-type as json?

Comment: or XML, personally I like XML but both are easy to work with. Do that then wrap the response in a XML format with tags.